# x86_64-linux-gnu-ld cannot find -lyaml

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

Having this problem every time i run my crystal application. Search over the internet but unfortunately nothing solves my problem. The screenshot of the actual error is below[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Oh sorry so i should just put the actual error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `libyaml-dev`:

```
sudo apt install libyaml-dev
```